# Undo downvote without the need to edit downvoted answer

Tags: feature-request, comments, downvotes, downvote-reason, locked-votes

Context:

- user B downvotes user A's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13519858/1376657) and leaves a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519644/how-to-solve-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-in-python/13519858?noredirect=1#comment47269395_13519858) saying that the answer does not address the question;
- user A explains how the answer *does* indeed address the question;
- user B agrees but cannot undo the downvote unless the answer is edited;

Can user B undo the downvote without any (pointless) editing by A on the answer? If not, why and how is this kind of case solved?

Comment: It doesn't happen that often.  It's only happened to me once, (I mistakenly downvoted when intending to upvote).  When I realized I' d screwed up, I edited in a period at the end, reversed the vote and removed the period with another edit.  I commented, explaining to the poster what I'd done.  Problem fixed!

Answer (score 5):

I think in cases like you describe it typically happens that answer would benefit from the edit that adds an extended explanation provided in comments. After all, since one reader found it unclear without such an explanation, it is possible that others will too.

Such an edit would naturally unlock the vote, making it unnecessary to complicate system with an extra rule (which, [as they say](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49262/165773), additionally carries a risk of abuse).

Worth noting that one doesn't necessarily need to wait for post author to do an edit. I for one typically do this edit myself (with summary like ["clarification copied into post from comments"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194293/165773)) and then retract my prior vote.

Comment: The "additional" explanation comment was just a reiteration of the content of the answer (a meta-explanation, if you will). Apparently the downvoter simply didn't read the answer, just glanced at it.

Comment: @NadirSampaoli this means the case fall in rate fraction when there's no benefit in edit (note I wrote "typically the case" - not _always_). These are uncomfortable, really, but in my experience too rare to seriously worry (otherwise I'd collect stats and raised feature request myself)