# Expire vote locks after a month

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, downvotes, voting, upvotes

Currently, we can't un-upvote or un-downvote answers we voted on in the past. This is to prevent strategic voting and is generally a good thing©.

However, sometimes I want to un-upvote or un-downvote an answer once I changed my views on the subject or know it better. Gaining an understanding in a language/framework/library/system is very common when programming and often in retrospect I'd vote differently.

It would be really nice if we could retract votes after a duration - probably a month.

Related questions on meta:

- [Can we remove vote lock-in?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265858/can-we-remove-vote-lock-in)
- [Undo downvote without the need to edit downvoted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289885/undo-downvote-without-the-need-to-edit-downvoted-answer?lq=1)
- [What's the purpose of locking a vote down until the next edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251232/whats-the-purpose-of-locking-a-vote-down-until-the-next-edit?lq=1)

---

Opening on Meta SO and not Meta SE because I'm not sure this "learning of the field" applies in some sites - maybe it does.

Comment: At that point you've defeated the purpose of locking votes in the first place, as someone can strategically vote and then go back a month or however long you set it later to undo the downvotes.

Comment: @Servy you really think people would go back a month and do that? The fact every company out there has a "money back guarantee" people miss indicates otherwise.

Comment: Well the feature is there because people were coming back several days later to undo the votes.  If you're assuming people are never going to come back to undo the votes then you might as well just get rid of it entirely.  Someone who's going to go back in a few days is just as likely to come back in a month.

Answer (score 8):

I usually just suck it up.

Sometimes I'll post a new answer if I later realized a better answer exists.

Sometimes, when e.g. I find I was wrong to downvote (e.g. after other people clarified context I missed) I'll explicitly edit the post with a comment like

```
<!-- edit so I can un-downvote -->
```

That unlocks the vote too. It's almost cheating the rules, but can be done ethically by leaving the comment for the OP. (Sometimes I'll leave a readily visible comment for other users too, or just +1 an existing comment that already makes the required point).

Very rarely I would take the time to remove an upvote. I'm not sure I ever did.

Answer (score 6):

At the rate that programming languages change or advance, some answers quickly become deprecated or wrong. Removing this vote lock would give people a chance to remove votes on say, a `mysql_query` PHP question, that was relevant when `mysqli_*` or `PDO` was not around.

I'll inform Woodhouse to place my upvote when he gets back with my Tactilnecks.

Comment: Very solid use case.

Comment: Answers don't generally become "wrong", even if applied to an older context. In addition, I don't think ["outdated" answers deserve downvotes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265440/372643) (in that what appears outdated only needs to be put in the context of the version at the time it was answered). I'd agree that some `mysql_query` answers have the problem of being vulnerable to injections for example (even with "real escape"), but they had the problem back then, as well as now (which could warrant downvotes back then too).

Comment: Just for clarity, notice I said remove vote, not downvote

Answer (score 2):

I've never really been all that enthusiastic about the strategic voting argument here. While I suspect there is probably some subtle influence, I'm skeptical that it warrants such a heavy-handed restriction.

**[But there are other behaviors that do warrant it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265858/can-we-remove-vote-lock-in/291292#291292)**

> None of these are hypothetical, BTW. Nor is this list exhaustive. Folks have done or tried to do all of this at one point or another, and while vote-locking doesn't eliminate them it does make accomplishing them considerably slower and more labor-intensive for the griefer. I don't know if any of this factored into the original decision to implement it, but it wouldn't surprise me - and even if griefing wasn't a concern back then, I'd be very reluctant to remove the locks now because of it.