# Retracting the downvote even if the answer was not edited

Tags: feature-request, voting

At the moment it is not possible to retract a downvote when the answer was not edited.

I have DV-ted the answer by mistake (I wanted to upvote it). But system does not let me change it.

> You last voted on this answer 15 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in
> unless this answer is edited.

I feel bad as the answer is good and for sure it does not deserve a DV. I do not see any rational reason for this restriction.

---

After reading the links I understand the reason. I think you should lift this restriction for high-rank users. I do not think that they will abuse the reputation system.

Comment: @MrMythical:  I would argue against that as a dupe since...well, the OP isn't asking *what* the restriction is, they're making a suggestion to *undo* the restriction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undo downvote without the need to edit downvoted answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289885/undo-downvote-without-the-need-to-edit-downvoted-answer)

Comment: @Makoto The OP says *"I do not see any rational reason for this restriction"*, which is why the feature-request was proposed. The dupe I proposed shows why this is there

Comment: @Mr I have noticed my error after 5 minutes. Why can't I change it? It makes no sense in my opinion.

Comment: @MrMythical:  A better dupe has happened along which addresses the heart of why the restriction cannot be lifted, so I'll go with that.

Comment: You have enough reputation to just edit the post yourself. This is a workaround for such rare situations.

Comment: @Dharman Good idea :)

Comment: @0___________ "It makes no sense in my opinion". Yes okay but did you try to answer for yourself why the lock-in was implemented in the first place? This whole meta post reads like "I don't like it so I want it gone". But the people who built the site are not stupid (disclaimer: this is a feature from long ago, this does not reflect my opinion of changes being done lately...), surely it's there for a valid reason, right? Feature requests work a lot better if they come from a good foundation - understanding.

Comment: @Gimby I usually do not think about spammers and other reputation fight idiots, because I simply never do it. A bit naive probably.

Comment: @Gimby Gimby please comment only on what I wrote not what **you** think I had in mind.  Never said that people running this site are stupid. I have the right to have my opinion and I still think that people having a high reputation should not have this restriction. Trust me, after gaining some reputation you will not care about points

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You had five whole minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/175248) to consider un-downvoting an answer.  Your only real option is to "wait" for an edit to the answer so that you can undo your votes.

Next time, don't be so hasty to vote.

N.B:  By "wait" I'm implying you could just edit the answer yourself (appropriately, of course) to get around the limitation.

Comment: I understand the reason, but I think this restriction should be only for people having a lower reputation. I have not seen anyonehavin rep > 15000 to abuse the system this way

Comment: Erm, given you can't do this at all regardless of rep, it's not surprising you've not seen anyone having high reputation abusing the system in this way.

Comment: @0___________: I mean, if the edit is a necessary and appropriate edit, it's hardly *abuse*.  It's an unpleasant workaround, sure, so seeing people make silly/trivial edits just because they want to undo a vote is not a normal or typical use case.